# Python - Mask specific values of a grid

Tags: numpy, grid, mask

I would like to mask values of a grid.
As example i want to mask all values of "t < 0" to do calculation after.
I try to use a conditionnal if but it doesnt work...

```
import numpy as np

Lx=10.
Ly=10.

x0 = 2

YA, XA = np.mgrid[0:Ly, 0:Lx]

t = XA - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain what you want to do *after* you mask the array. Do you want to alter the unmasked values? Then

```
mask = t < 0
YA[~mask] = ...
```

might be all you need.

On the other hand, if you need to compute statistics on arrays with masked value, you may find using [NumPy masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#masked-arrays-arithmetics) more convenient:

```
YA = np.ma.masked_array(YA, mask)
```